# parse the text for href content in android

Tags: java, android, html

I have the following text

his is to confirm that you have successfully changed your preferences regarding your Buy.com email subscriptions. Please allow 5 to 7 business days for this change to fully take effect.

Should you want to change your preferences again, please do so at:

https://ssl.buy.com/AC/EmailPreferenceCenter.aspx?EmailAddr=xxx.com />

Buy.com realizes you have many choices for online shopping, and we thank you for your business! Please feel free to contact Buy.com with any additional questions or concerns, and we will be glad to help.

Sincerely,

Rakuten Buy.com Customer Support

**I want to display the message as**

his is to confirm that you have successfully changed your preferences regarding your Buy.com email subscriptions. Please allow 5 to 7 business days for this change to fully take effect.

Should you want to change your preferences again, please do so at:

https://ssl.buy.com/AC/EmailPreferenceCenter.aspx?EmailAddr=xxx.com

Buy.com realizes you have many choices for online shopping, and we thank you for your business! Please feel free to contact Buy.com with any additional questions or concerns, and we will be glad to help.

Sincerely,

Rakuten Buy.com Customer Support

I tried the following :

text.setTextHtml.fromHtml(htmlText));

but this does not preserve the styling like paragraph formatting, line breaks  etc .
SO how can i achieve this styling when my text has references to a href ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use spans :
search for "android spans" or see the following link